# Slimbookbattery status icon

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel

I installed Slimbook battery so I could manage my laptop's battery better than with the tools provided in the system settings, but I am unable to add the icon to the tray for better access (rather than going to Applications > Accessories > Slimbook battery preferences and then having to type my password).

Has anyone encountered some similar issue and found a solution? I'm running elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera, everything up-to-date. I tried installing `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` and rebooting. Typing in the command to start slimbookbattery writes that it is already started/executed.

Answer (score 0):

elementary OS doesn't support app indicators out of the box and since it doesn't use GNOME Shell, the extension you mentioned won't work.
Have a look at [Ayatana](https://github.com/lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana) which is an extension providing indicators in elementary's wingpanel.